# How would you 'force' users to fill out a profile before viewing ASP.NET MVC site?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, redirect, asp.net-membership, profile

After my users register the first time, I want them to have to fill out a profile page within the website.  I have it set so that it redirects them during log-in if they have not filled out the profile before, but if they type in another url within the website they are currently free to go anywhere they want after that redirect.

What is the best way to require users to the profile page when they try to visit any page on my site until they have completed the profile?

Is this best done with something like: 'if (!user is verified) - redirect to profile page'  placed at the top of every controller?  Is there a more elegant solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Start with implementing a custom Action Filter (IActionFilter):

```
public class ProfileRequiredActionFilter : IActionFilter
{
    #region Implementation of IActionFilter

    public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        //TODO: Check if the Authenticated User has a profile.

        //If Authenicated User doesn't have a profile...
        filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult("Path-To-Create-A-Profile");
    }

    public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Then register the Action Filter globally inside the ***RegisterGlobalFilters*** method of the  Global.asax...

```
public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
{
    filters.Add(new ProfileRequiredActionFilter());
}
```

Note: If you don't want this filter to be applied globally, you can create an ActionFilterAttribute instead and apply it to Controllers and/or Action methods...

```
public class ProfileRequiredAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    #region Implementation of IActionFilter

    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);

        //TODO: Check if the Authenticated User has a profile.

        //If Authenicated User doesn't have a profile...
        filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult("Path-To-Create-A-Profile");
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You could create a Base controller and have all your other controllers inherit from that.
Then have an OnActionExecuting method in it with something like...

```
protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
{
    base.OnActionExecuting(context);

    // If the user has not filled out their profile, redirect them
    if(CurrentUser != null && !CurrentUser.IsVerified)
    {
        context.Result = new RedirectResult("/User/Profile/" + CurrentUser.ID);
    }
}
```

Comment: I would recommend moving it from a Base Controller to a Global Action Filter (IActionFilter) instead. This gives you more flexibility by not requiring all controllers inherit the base controller in order to perform the Profile check.

Comment: @RobRichardson How would I do that exactly?

Comment: I ended up going with this approach as I already have access to the 'Custom Principal' property in my base controller.